# PostgreSQL grouping

Tags: postgresql, group-by, grouping

I would like to group values according to values in over columns.
This is an example:
[image]

I would like to get the output:

```
{{-30,-50,20},{-20,30,60},{-30,NULL or other value, 20}}
```

I managed to arrive to:

```
SELECT array_agg("val") 
FROM my_table 
WHERE "t_id" = 1  
GROUP BY "m_id";

{{-30,-50,20},{-20,30,60},{-30,20}}
```

What would be the best approach?

Comment: Maybe join a synthetic table to ensure the "expected" rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table my_table (
    t_id int,
    m_id int,
    s_id int,
    val int
);
insert into my_table (t_id, m_id, s_id, val) values
(1,1,1,-30),
(1,1,2,-50),
(1,1,3,20),
(1,2,1,-20),
(1,2,2,30),
(1,2,3,60),
(1,3,1,-30),
(1,3,3,20);
```

---

```
select array_agg(val order by s_id) 
from
    my_table t
    right join
    (
        (
            select distinct t_id, m_id
            from my_table
        ) a
        cross join
        (
            select distinct s_id
            from my_table
        ) b
    ) s using (t_id, m_id, s_id)
where t_id = 1  
group by m_id
order by m_id
;
   array_agg   
---------------
 {-30,-50,20}
 {-20,30,60}
 {-30,NULL,20}
```